# Response.Flush not working

Tags: .net, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Buffer = False
        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " " & i
            Response.Flush()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Next
    End Sub
```

I expect this to print 0, then wait two seconds, then print 0 1 then wait two seconds etc.  However, it simply waits 12 seconds and prints everything.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a Windows Form app or an ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 0):

In your code above it will sleep the main thread for 2 seconds and because to it, you can not see the data or the form until the complete code is executed. You can use timer, and set interval of 2000 to it. Like ..

```
   Dim i As Integer = 0
   ' You have to Start Timer1 like, Timer1.Enabled = True
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If i >= 6 Then  
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            i = 0
        Else
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " " & i
            ' Code here to execute for 0 to 5
            i += 1
        End If

    End Sub
```